# Is correct replace content in the same place without remove the previous content model using Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a web application developed with Backbone.js. In the application, there are some buttons that remove the content view, but not the content model when pushed. For example, If I push the same button multiple times, the content is replaced, but the model of that content isn't removed.
How can I remove it?

I know how to remove the content with other different button, but I don't know how to remove the content if the same button (or other button not destined to delete but to add) is pushed.
The example code:
HTML:

```
<button class="ShowCam"></button>
<button class="camClose"></button>
<button class="anotherButton"></button>
```

JS:

```
var camContent = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "body",     
    events: {
        "click .ShowCam": "addContentCam", 
                "click .anotherButton": "otherAddContentFunction"                   
    },          
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.model = new ContentCollection();
        this.model.on("add", this.contentAdded);
        this.model.on("remove", this.removeContentCam); 
    },                  
    addContentCam: function(event) {
        this.model.add({ modelName: "IPcam"});          
    contentAdded: function(content) {
        if (content.view == null) {
           var templ_name = 'cam';                                                  
           content.view = new ContentView({
                  model: content,
                  template: $.trim($("[data-template='"+ templ_name +"'] div").html() || "Template not found!")});
           $("div.camBox").empty(); 
           this.$el.find(".content").find("div.camBox").append(content.view.render().el);                                           
        }                   
    },  
    removeContentCam: function(content) {
        if (content.view != null) { 
            content.view.remove();              
        }
        content.clear();  //Clear the properties of the model   
    }   
}); 
var ContentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "div",
    template: null,
    events: {
          "click .camClose": "removeView" 
    },
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.template = this.options.template; 
    },
    render: function() {        
        this.$el.html(Mustache.render(this.template, this.model.toJSON())); 
        return this; 
    },
    removeView: function() {
        this.model.collection.remove(this.model); //Remove the model of the collection
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: Just to second @amchang87, this question is a bit hard to understand.  Stuff like this bit "I know how remove a content with other different button, but i don't know how remove content if the same button (or other button not destinated to delete but yes to add) is pushed." isn't even valid English.  I tried to answer the question anyway, but I'm honestly not sure if my answer addresses your question.

Comment: Referring to code: When `.ShowCam` is clicked, a model is added to the collection and a view is created and rendered. If `ShowCam`is clicked again, a model is added to the collection and a view is created and redered again, but previous model isn't removed, only the view, with `$("div.camBox").empty();` (I think). However, if `.camClose`is clicked, present model is removed of the collection, but not if `.anotherButton` is clicked or  `ShowCam`is clicked multiple times. I want to remove unused models, if it is more correct. Do you understand me? Sorry for my English.

Comment: If `.ShowCam`is clicked multiple times, a solution is unbind the click event, but if `.anotherButton` is clicked the previous model isn't removed. Is neccesary for more efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript uses a garbage collection system to do its memory management.  What this means is that you can delete *anything* simply by removing all references to it (well, technically it doesn't actually get deleted until the garbage collector gets to it, but essentially it's deleted).

So, if you want to make sure that a model gets removed, you don't need to call any special methods, you just need to do `delete someView.model` on every view (or other place in your code) that references that model.

You can actually see all this in practice if you look at the `remove` method on `Backbone.View`.  You'll find that all it really does (besides triggering events) is call an internal method `_removeReference`.  And what does `_removeReference` do?  This:

```
  if (this == model.collection) {
    delete model.collection;
  }
  // (there's also an event-related line here)
```

Now, all that being said, if you're making a new view to replace an old one, and they both have the same model ... well you likely shouldn't be making a new view in the first place.  The more standard Backbone way of handling such situations is to just re-call render on the view (instead of making a new one).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for response. Now, the application makes a new model and view when the button is clicked. Then, is possible re-call render the view shown above? Maybe with id?

Comment: It really depends on how you write your render method.  If it's just (like in your case) a `this.$el.html(...` then you should totally be able to re-render it.  If you're having trouble accessing the view after the fact, you can always store it in jQuery data: `this.$el.data('view', this)`.